# How can you tell that the aerofoil has an asymmetric section only by looking at Lift to drag ratio against AOA?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, aerodynamics, lift

I am new to aeronautics and I am interested to know how can the section of an aerofoil be determined just by looking at its lift-to-drag ratio against angle of attack ( $C_l/C_d$ as a function of AOA).

Specifically, I would like to know:

What are the key characteristics that experts look for when analyzing the $C_l/C_d$ curve of an aerofoil?
How do they use these characteristics to identify the section of the aerofoil?
Are there any other factors that should be considered when evaluating an aerofoil's performance?
I am seeking reliable sources or insights from experts in the field of aeronautics. Any recommendations or additional information would be appreciated.

Comment: Crossposted to https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/98365

Comment: Having now seen the data plotted on the aviation site (after posting my answer here), it's clear that you have bigger problems than just determining whether the shape is symmetrical or not (like how can your 2D foil have negative drag?)

Comment: Also, since you already knew the foil section, why are you asking how to tell if it's symmetrical or not?

Comment: @D.Halsey I know my experiment went wrong in a very bad way probably due to the setup ( still need to check that), and I am asking in the general case, not in the case where I know my airfoil section, I heard that you can tell a lot of things just by looking at the graph including airfoil section and was curious to know how is it done! Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses the specific question asked in the title, not the much broader discussion requested in the longer text.

If an airfoil has a symmetrical section shape, then its curves of lift and drag as functions of angle of attack will be anti-symmetric and symmetric, respectively. Therefore, its curve of lift-to-drag ratio will be anti-symmetric.

That will not be true for an asymmetrical shape.

Beyond that, it would be much more difficult to deduce more about the shape. It would be necessary (just to get started) to specify the Reynolds number, as the lift and drag characteristics strongly depend on it.